# When creating a user, the request ignore the value entered and use the default one instead

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I've been following a course in node/express and was doing the same, my problem now is that when I send a POST request with Postman to create a user, here's my request

```
{
    "name": "sam",
    "email": "sam@sam.io",
    "password": "pass1234",
    "passwordConfirm":"pass1234",
    "role": "admin" 
}
```

In the response, the role is getting ignored and uses the default value declared in the schema, here's the code of my userModel.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const validator = require('validator');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please tell us your name']
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide your email'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please provide a valid email']
  },
  photo: {
    type: String
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'guide', 'lead-guide', 'admin'],
    default: 'user'
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide a password'],
    minlength: 8,
    select: false
  },
  passwordConfirm: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please confirm your password'],
    validate: {
      // WORK ONLY ON SAVE
      validator: function(el) {
        return el === this.password;
      },
      message: `Passwords don't match`
    }
  },
  passwordChangedAt: {
    type: Date
  }
});

userSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
  // only run if password isn't modified
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 14);

  this.passwordConfirm = undefined;
  next();
});

userSchema.methods.correctPassword = async function(
  candidatePassword,
  userPassword
) {
  return await bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, userPassword);
};

userSchema.methods.changedPasswordAfter = function(JWTTimestamp) {
  if (this.passwordChangedAt) {
    const changedTimestamp = parseInt(
      this.passwordChangedAt.getTime() / 1000,
      10
    );

    return JWTTimestamp < changedTimestamp;
  }

  // False means NOT changed
  return false;
};

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

I'll note as well that I've had a similar issue with passwordChangedAt, when I specify it in the request, the value get completely ignored and not get added in the database.
If anyone of you can help I'd greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add the code from your post request that saves the user to the database?

Comment: Oh yes thanks for reminding me, I didn't add it there, fixed it now thank you!